# how to use autocomplete in TextArea in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, textarea, textfield

javafx provides support of autocomplete for TextField i want to use that feature for textArea

```
String[] autosuggestions = {"test","testing","etc etc"};
    TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(inputTextField, autosuggestions);
```

please help how can i use that for TextArea 
something like this

```
String[] autosuggestions = {"test","testing","etc etc"};
        TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(inputTextArea, autosuggestions);
```

any workaround will be appreciated please help

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the TextArea component and roll it yourself; this example (https://gist.github.com/floralvikings/10290131) does that with TextField, the same sort of process could be done with TextArea to select from an array of Strings.

On edit, you could check  if the word near the caret position are partial completions from the list, then just do it all manually with the popup that the example uses.

The example implements a change listener:

```
textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>()
{
@Override
public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observableValue, String s, String s2) { ... } });
```

And that hides/shows a popup populated at `private void populatePopup(List<String> searchResult) {...}`

You could extend the text area, then use a similar popup. The tricky part is finding the caret position for the textarea, getting the word being edited, then being able to insert the completion from the popup into the text area in the right place.